# Overlay state outlines on choropleth in Altair

Tags: python-3.x, vega, altair, vega-lite

I am unable to overlay state outlines over a county level choropleth in Altair. 
I am using altair's layer method to achieve this. 
However, it is taking the stroke color of the state outline chart and drawing county outlines with that color. 

This is my code:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

us_states = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, 'states')
us_counties = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, 'counties')
unemp_data = data.unemployment(sep='\t')
unemp_data.head()

plot = alt.Chart(us_counties).mark_geoshape(stroke='white').project(
type='albersUsa'
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(unemp_data, 'id', ['rate'])
).encode(
    color='rate:Q'
).properties(
    width=700,
    height=400
)

outline = alt.Chart(us_states).mark_geoshape( stroke='black').project(
    type='albersUsa'
).properties(
    width=700,
    height=400
)

alt.layer(plot,outline)
```

I am getting the following result:
[Layered Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBBIZ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to be a bug in Vega, wherein if two data sources are identical the stroke properties overwrite each other. I managed to work around this by adding a `"#"` to the end of one of the URLs to trick Vega into thinking the datasets are different:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

us_states = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, 'states')
us_counties = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url+"#", 'counties')
unemp_data = data.unemployment.url

plot = alt.Chart(us_counties).mark_geoshape(stroke='white').project(
type='albersUsa'
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(unemp_data, 'id', ['rate'])
).encode(
    color='rate:Q'
).properties(
    width=700,
    height=400
)

outline = alt.Chart(us_states).mark_geoshape(stroke='black', fillOpacity=0).project(
    type='albersUsa'
).properties(
    width=700,
    height=400
)

alt.layer(plot,outline)
```

[image]

(Additionally, I specified `fillOpacity=0` because this default is going to change in Vega-Lite 4).

Comment: I've filed a bug report here: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5655